# Is there a context free grammar that is both in Chomsky Normal Form and ambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I know that converting an ambiguous context free grammar (CFG) to be in Chomsky Normal Form (CNF) might make it unambiguous, but is it a method that necessarily makes any CFG unambiguous? My knowledge tells me that the only way to prove a CFG to be ambiguous is to build two different parse trees, but i cannot find the relevance with the above statement. And, since proving a CFG to be unambiguous is undecidable, I don't know how to prove the statement to be correct as well. Please give some ideas or a counter example.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not: there are context-free languages that are [inherently ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Inherently_ambiguous_languages), meaning that they have no unambiguous grammar. The accepted answer at [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/inherent-ambiguity-of-the-language-l-2-anbmcm-m-n-geq-1-cup-a) sketches a proof of inherent ambiguity of a particular context-free language. Since any context-free language has a grammar in Chomsky normal form, this shows that such a grammar can be ambiguous.